# Application called from the exited activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I've used the following code in my application to exit from it when the user clicks the button. It is working. But the problem is, when I open the application again, it will not be started from the main activity. Instead, it will be started from the activity where i exited.

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
FarmerDetails.this.startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Full code:

```
public class FarmerDetails extends Activity {
Button ok,old,ok1,exit;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.labour); 
    ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ok1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    exit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_exit);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            FarmerDetails.this.startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }

    });
     ok1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(final View v) {
             Intent next=new Intent(FarmerDetails.this,Fetch.class);
             startActivity(next);




         }
     });   



     ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(final View v) {
             Intent next=new Intent(FarmerDetails.this,newfarmer1.class);
             startActivity(next);




         }
     });   



}
public void onDestroy()
{
    System.gc();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem and how to avoid?

I need to start the application from the main activity after exited.

Comment: Where are you exiting from the application? Post that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.
When the user pressed the exit button it loads the first Activity that runs when your app starts, in my case "main".

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), main.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(i);
```

The above code clears all the activities except for main. main is the first activity that is brought up when the user runs the program.

Then put this code inside the main's onCreate, to signal when it should self destruct when the 'Exit' message is passed.

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult from callerActivity A while starting this Activity B and before calling finish() setResult(someint) and onActivityResult of A if resultcode==someint
 finish the activity A  and so on..You need to destroy your main activity to re launch from main activity

Comment: ohkk clear top works for same kind of activity..What u need to do is startActivityforResult from which you are starting this activity..and while finishing setResult which will be recieved in the mainActivity and finish your main activity as well

Comment: Until your mainActivity is not finished it remains in Stack and when u again start the app it will show the previously exited activity..U need to destroy the main activity if u want to launch the main activity on app start